# Are there any spam filers involved when receiving mail@app.appspotmail.com

Tags: email, google-app-engine, spam

[Preconditions]
I have developed a software running at google-appengine (GAE) that receives mail and reacts to them. So far so good, it all works as expected.

To receive mails into GAE you must send mail to xxx@myapp.appspotmail.com but as I wanted to use nicer mailadresses I have set up a catch-all adress for one of my domains that forwards all mails to myapp.appspotmail.com. This also works well.

[Question]
If this project gets popular it could potentially have some 10 000 users which all will send around 100 mails/day. The mails are sent automaticly from a 3G enabled device and contains status of the device. This makes me think that a spamfilter would probably consider the mails as spam. And as all mails are routed through the catch-all adress I belive this makes it even more suspicious.

1. Are there any spamfilters active for mails that are received to appspotmail.com
2. Are there any risk that the mailserver that forwards all mails will be blacklisted somehow?
3. Anything else you think of that would potentially prevent me from receiving all mails.

[Clarification]
The devices sending the mails are survaillancecameras which *only* has support for sending mails. Sometimes with status messages, and sometimes with a photo attached. The cameras can not be configured in any other way than to send mails or (MMS :-D).

Kind Regards
Thomas

Comment: can you explain why are using emails instead of calling your server directly? it will not scale well with emails, regardless of the spam issue.

Comment: Hi Zig. The only reason for using mails is that I dont manufacture the devices that sends the mail. Why will it not scale well?